# How to send property values containing '='?

Tags: artifactory

According to your [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution), a user can send properties via the upload URI.

How to pass = as a property value?

I have tried with \= and %3D, but in both the cases I get a truncated value. All the properties after the problematic one are lost, too.

This same problem affects the jfrog-cli-go.

Answer (score 2):

Jfrog-cli version 1.5.0 upload command will support uploading files with properties contains special characters.

```
jfrog rt u froggy.tgz my-local-repo --props=prop==+\~ // upload froggy.tgz and set prop as property with =+\~ as value.
```

Follow Jfrog-cli releases at: 
https://bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/

Comment: great. I will be very happy when it will become available. Thus, I think that you're implicitly speaking of the issue https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/issues/18

Comment: @nilleb Jfrog-cli version 1.5 is officially released.